# Closed path integral

Tags: integration, contour-integration, complex-integration

Thanks for coming in

This is a very basic question and I'm sorry to ask about it, since I really couldn't figure it out

I have searched for closed path integral on this site and found a lot of them but still couldn't figure it out why? 
let say I have closed path $S$ from $(1,-i)\space\space\space\rightarrow(1,i)\\(1,i)\space\space\space\space\space\space\rightarrow(-1,i)\\(-1,i)\space\space\space\rightarrow(-1,-i)\\(-1,-i)\rightarrow(1,-i)$

and  $\int_S\frac{2z+6}{z^2+6z+13}$dz

First, I did as following

$\int\frac{2z+6}{z^2+6z+13}dz=\ln(z^2+6z+13)$ for each path let says $S_1,S_2,S_3,S_4$and then I summed them together

which gave me zero as an answer

however, I also found that if I did it differently, it could give me a different answer (a correct one, I believe) by

$\int_S\frac{2z+6}{z^2+6z+13}dz = \int_S \frac{1}{z+3-2i}dz+\int_S\frac{1}{z+3+2i}dz$

(edit#1begin)

$\int_S \frac{1}{z+3-2i} = \int_{1-i}^{1+i}\frac{1}{z+3-2i}+\int_{1+i}^{-1+i}\frac{1}{z+3-2i}+\int_{-1+i}^{-1-i}\frac{1}{z+3-2i}+\int_{-1-i}^{1-i}\frac{1}{z+3-2i}\\
= \ln\frac{4-i}{4-3i}\frac{2-i}{4-i}\frac{2-3i}{2-i}\frac{4-3i}{2-3i} = \ln(1)\\
= \ln(e^{2\pi i}) = 2\pi i
$

(edit#1end)

then I got an answer as $4\pi i$ instead

So, my question is why can't I go with the first solution? what did I miss?

Thank you

Comment: How do you get $4\pi i$ when the poles $z = -3 \pm 2i$ are not inside $S$? Both of the integrals should give $0$.

Comment: @md2perpe 
I got it from $\ln(1)$ then substitute with  $e^{2\pi i}$

Sorry, but I don't get it when you said the poles $z$ are not inside $S$ 

Could you clarify it? maybe I did it wrong, but I also need the right answer 
Thanks

Comment: $S$ is a square with corners in $(\pm 1, \pm i)$. The integrands $\frac{1}{z-3\pm2i}$ have [poles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_(complex_analysis)) at $z = 3\pm2i$, which are outside of $S$. That means that the integrands are holomorphic inside $S$, which implies that the integrals are $0$.

Comment: I didn't understand how you did the computations. Can you expand on that so that we can point out the exact error?

Comment: @md2perpe I edited it inside the question already, please have a look

Comment: Why $\ln 1 = 2\pi i$ and not $\ln 1 = 0$?

Comment: @md2perpe that's indeed a good question 

I literally have no idea why I chose $2\pi i$ over $0$ but I have recognised this kind of question and know that it most likely not equal to $0$, so I chose $2\pi i$

Comment: In this case the answer is actually $0$ as has already been pointed out. The reason is that the contour doesn't enclose any pole.

Comment: so if the poles are inside $S$  then the answer will not be zero but $2\pi i$ ?

Comment: One pole of the form $\frac{1}{z-a}$ will contribute with a factor $2\pi i$. But there might of course be more poles, and they might be weighted, e.g.
$$\frac{3}{z-2} + \frac{2}{z-3}$$
If both $2$ and $3$ are inside the contour, then the integral of this expression will be $3 \cdot 2\pi i + 2 \cdot 2\pi i = 10 \pi i.$

Comment: According to your example, what if one of the poles is not inside the contour 

let says $3$ is outside of the contour, then can I say the integral of expression will be only $2\cdot2\pi i$?

Comment: If $3$ is outside of the contour, then we only get a contribution from $\frac{3}{z-2}$ so the integral will be $3 \cdot 2\pi i$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this as a simpler example. Compute
$$\int_S\frac{dz}{z}$$
over your contour. The answer is $2\pi i$ by calculus of residues. But
you could say the indefinite integral is $\ln(z)$ and sum as you did
over each edge and get zero.

This is fallacious of course: $\ln$ is a "multivalued" function on the
nonzero complexes, and there is no branch of the function that is continuous on the whole contour $S$. The same problem holds in your example. There is no continuous branch of $\ln(z^2+6z+13)$ defined on $S$.
By the time you've gone round the contour you've hit a different value
of $\ln(z^2+6z+13)$ to that you started with. These different values
must differ by a multiple of $2\pi i$, so an answer of $4\pi i$ is quite plausible...

Comment: Thank you for your quick response

After I saw your mention on calculus of residues and fallacy of $\ln$ I began google on those and as you said, there is no continuous branch of my function defined by $S$ path left afterwards. It is clearly that this it has been changed from the one I started with. When it comes to complex analysis, it seems that some elementary calculus won't work anymore 

Thank you very much, your explanation is what I was looking for

Comment: After reading other comments, could it be that my function's answer should be zero on both methods?

Answer (score 1):

The solutions of the equation $z^2+6z+13=0$ are $-3\pm 2i$. Hence there is a region $D$ such that $S \subseteq D$, $-3\pm 2i \notin D$ and $f(z):=\frac{2z+6}{z^2+6z+13}$ is holomorphic on $D$. Then Cauchy says:

$$\int_Sf(z) dz  =0.$$

Comment: I was just going to write a comment under Lord Shark the Unknown's answer that the branch point is outside of the square when your answer showed up.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I wonder about the branch point is outside of the square when you said $ -3\pm 2i \notin D$, could you explain this part a little more

Comment: Take $D=\{z \in \mathbb C: |z|<2\}$